# Passing primitives to an OCMock's stub

Tags: xcode, primitive, ocmock

I'm learning how to use OCMock to test my iPhone's project and I have this scenario: a HeightMap class with a `getHeightAtX:andY:` method, and a Render class using `HeightMap`. I'm trying to unit test Render using some `HeightMap` mocks. This works:

```
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Chunk class]];
int h = 0;
[[[mock stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(h)] getHeightAtX:0 andY:0];
```

Of course, works only for `x=0` and `y=0`. I want to test using a "flat" height map. This means I need to do something like this:

```
id chunk = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Chunk class]];
int h = 0;
[[[chunk stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(h)] getHeightAtX:[OCMArg any] andY:[OCMArg any]];
```

But this raises two compilation warnings:

> warning: passing argument 1 of `'getHeightAtX:andY:'` makes integer from pointer without a cast

and a runtime error:

> unexpected method invoked: `'getHeightAtX:0 andY:0 stubbed: getHeightAtX:15545040 andY:15545024'`

What am I missing? I found no way to pass a `anyValue` to this mock.

Comment: It's possible to edit OCMock to do this, if it's worth your time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916115/ocmock-passing-any-cgsize/16923742#16923742

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OCMock doesn't currently support loose matching of primitive arguments. There's a discussion about potential changes to support this [on the OCMock forums](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=72), though it seems to have stalled.

The only solution I've found is to structure my tests in such a way that I know the primitive values that will be passed in, though it's far from ideal.

Comment: has anything changed since you made this post about this topic?

Comment: I believe you can now do this with [OCMArg setToValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(some_primitive)]. It basically wraps the primitive with an NSValue. At least, the "features" page shows this as an example: http://ocmock.org/features/.

Comment: @stuckj that doesn't solve OP's problem. `setToValue` allows you to stub a method that takes a pointer argument. Generally the method would assign some value to that pointer. `setToValue` allows you to assign a value when the stub intercepts the call. OP is trying to do a loose match of a primitive argument. @Andrew_Park has the (now) correct answer, to use `ignoringNonObjectArgs`.

Answer (score 50):

It's been awhile since this question has been asked but I ran into this issue myself and couldn't find a solution anywhere. OCMock now supports `ignoringNonObjectArgs` so an example of an `expect` would be

```
[[[mockObject expect] ignoringNonObjectArgs] someMethodWithPrimitiveArgument:5];
```

the 5 doesn't actually do anything, just a filler value

Comment: Also a warning, if you have a method you're stubbing and using the `ignoringNonObjectArgs`, if you have a block AFTER the primitive argument and you're stubbing it with `[OCMarg checkWithBlock:]`, that block won't be evaluated (invoked)

Comment: This is now the correct answer to OP's question. Thank you for pointing this out! I hadn't seen this was added to OCMock.

Comment: +1 Given that it has weird side-effects I think the warning was a good call. A partial solution!

Comment: Is there also a macro syntax similar to `OCMExpect` to support this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [OCMockito](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito) instead.

It supports primitive argument matching.

For instance, in your case:

```
id chunk = mock([Chunk class]);
[[given([chunk getHeightAtX:0]) withMatcher:anything() forArgument:0] willReturnInt:0];
```

Comment: Ach, I like OCMockito, but it's all very much Y U NO PARTIAL MOCKING!?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **Andrew Park** answer you could make it a little bit more general and nice looking:

```
#define OCMStubIgnoringNonObjectArgs(invocation) \
({ \
    _OCMSilenceWarnings( \
        [OCMMacroState beginStubMacro]; \
        [[[OCMMacroState globalState] recorder] ignoringNonObjectArgs]; \
        invocation; \
        [OCMMacroState endStubMacro]; \
    ); \
})
```

The you can use it like that:

```
OCMStubIgnoringNonObjectArgs(someMethodParam:0 param2:0).andDo(someBlock)
```

You can do the same for expecting. This case is for stubbing as topic starter request. It was tested with OCMock 3.1.1.

Comment: Um, what object is `someMethodParam:0 param2:0` being invoked on?

Comment: object, which you're actually mocking

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

`id chunk = OCMClassMock([Chunk class])
OCMStub([chunk ignoringNonObjectArgs] getHeightAtX:0 andY:0]])`

Readmore at: http://ocmock.org/reference/#argument-constraints

Comment: Please provide a better description for your solution. Links are great, but they can break someday. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Despite being fairly hacky, the approach of using expectations to store the passed block to call later in the test code has worked for me:

```
- (void)testVerifyPrimitiveBlockArgument
{
    // mock object that would call the block in production
    id mockOtherObject = OCMClassMock([OtherObject class]);

    // pass the block calling object to the test object
    Object *objectUnderTest = [[Object new] initWithOtherObject:mockOtherObject];

    // store the block when the method is called to use later
    __block void (^completionBlock)(NSUInteger value) = nil;
    OCMExpect([mockOtherObject doSomethingWithCompletion:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id value) { completionBlock = value; return YES; }]]);

    // call the method that's being tested
    [objectUnderTest doThingThatCallsBlockOnOtherObject];

    // once the expected method has been called from `doThingThatCallsBlockOnOtherObject`, continue
    OCMVerifyAllWithDelay(mockOtherObject, 0.5);
    // simulate callback from mockOtherObject with primitive value, can be done on the main or background queue
    completionBlock(45);
}
```