# OCMock passing any CGSize

Tags: ios, unit-testing, primitive-types, ocmock, cgsize

I'm using OCMock and I'm trying to do to something like this in one of my tests:

```
[[mockScrollView expect] setContentSize:[OCMArg any]];
```

The problem is that `[OCMArg any]` returns an `id` type, and I want to use any `CGSize`, because I don't know it's exact value. How can I pass this argument?

Comment: This is a problem with OCMock. That said, mocking a view shouldn't generally be necessary. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With version 2.2 of OCMock you can use `ignoringNonObjectArgs`

```
[[mockScrollView expect] ignoringNonObjectArgs] setContentSize:dummySize];
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to accomplish that with OCMock.

An alternative is to create a hand made mock. This is a subclass of `UIScrollView` where you override `setContentSize:` assigning the given size to a ivar that later on you can inspect.

Other easier option is to use a real `UIScrollView` and check directly is the `contentSize` is the one you expect. I would go for this solution.

Comment: I agree that checking the result of the change in content size is a good way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it looks like you'd have to extend OCMock in order to accomplish this. You could follow this pattern...

**OCMArg.h**

```
// Add this:
+ (CGSize)anyCGSize;
```

**OCMArg.c**

```
// Add this:
+ (CGSize)anyCGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(0.1245, 5.6789);
}

// Edit this method:
+ (id)resolveSpecialValues:(NSValue *)value
{
    const char *type = [value objCType];

    // Add this:
    if(type[0] == '{')
    {
        NSString *typeString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:type encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        if ([typeString rangeOfString:@"CGSize"].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            CGSize size = [value CGSizeValue];
            if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeMake(0.1245, 5.6789)))
            {
                return [OCMArg any];
            }
        }
    }

    // Existing code stays the same...
    if(type[0] == '^')
    {
        void *pointer = [value pointerValue];
        if(pointer == (void *)0x01234567)
            return [OCMArg any];
        if((pointer != NULL) && (object_getClass((id)pointer) == [OCMPassByRefSetter class]))
            return (id)pointer;
    }
    return value;
}
```